# not showing admob banner with listview in android?

Tags: android, listview, layout, admob

in graphical layout the add is shown in the bottom , but when the app is run it cant shows any banner and give me warning that .....      " Not enough space to show ad. Needs 320x50 dp, but only has 288x464 dp. "   ,,,,,,,,can any one solve my problem .... thanks in advance 
here is XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/mainbg"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
    </ListView>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/game_ads"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="my ad ID"
        android:gravity="center" />

</RelativeLayout> 

enter code here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `listview` tag change

```
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
```

to

```
android:layout_above="@+id/game_ads"
```

and remove `android:gravity="center"` from `adview` tag

i.e. Rewrite your code as

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/mainbg"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/game_ads" >
    </ListView>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/game_ads"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="my ad ID"
      />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: sorry , same problem am facing sir :(

Comment: @user3326641 see edited answer and also clear project and retry.

Comment: also clean n restart eclipse but nothng happpens

Comment: thanks alot @giru Bhai .. i just remove the padding and it works :)

Comment: @user3326641 Happy to help,enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work :-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/mainbg"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/game_ads"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="my ad ID"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/game_ads" >
    </ListView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: sorry , same problem am facing sir :(

Comment: give the height/width to the admob widget as per android guidelines or use weight approach. Give listview 0.6 and Take a parent for admob and give it weight of 0.4. modify it accordingly. It will work

Comment: i hv done as you say but same prob n warning , it show list in 1/6 of screen but again no ad is shown in app

Comment: xml is ok. when you are running your app, can you see the admob widget below ? If yes then something is wrong in code

Comment: yes admob widget is shown in xml but nt in app running and in other layou and activities i hv same code for admob and other are fine and show admob , just in this layout i have face problem. kindly sir run the XML by your self , if you have time , thanks